# Grails IntegrationSpec rollback after each test case possible?

Tags: grails, integration-testing

So I have a spec that extends IntegrationSpec and I create and save some domain objects in my setup() method. I further have 6 testcases in this spec which all run fine when exectued individually. But when I execute all testcases in my spec they all fail except the first one. So I guess there is no rollback done in between the testcases. Is it possbile to rollback automatically after each testcase and if so, how? Or am I supposed to put each test case into a seperate integration test with the same setup?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Integration tests are running in a transaction that is rolled back after test execution by default.

In the docs it says:

> Integration tests differ from unit tests in that you have full access to the Grails environment within the test. Grails uses an in-memory H2 database for integration tests and clears out all the data from the database between tests.

For further information see [Grails Docs - 14.2 Integration Testing](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#integrationTesting).

If you have problems you would have to share some of these tests here so that we can take a look into it.

Comment: Have you tried using an integration test that extends IntegrationSpec? It doesn't roll back, hence OP's question :)  I've seen the same thing and it appears to be a bug that affects Spock tests but not regular JUnit tests.

Comment: but this would be a major issue, right? since grails creates a test class that is extending `IntegrationSpec` when doing `grails create-integration-test` (at least in 2.4.4). The docs tell exactly the rollback behavior in the chapter "integration testing". But as i see right now, in the docs they are extending from `GroovyTestCase` - which is not what the scaffolding plugin is doing currently. Im a little confused what is the "right" way of doing an integration test than...